# React component state variable updated but the fetch data is not triggered

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a very simple view component, in which I use [useSWR](https://swr.vercel.app/) to fetch data to show.

In short the `useSWR` hook is a HTTP cache invalidation strategy that wraps the `fetch`.

```
export const MyViewComponent = (props: {... }) => {
  // I have a state variable 'page'
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1); 

  // fetches the data from backend
  const { data, error } = useSWR('/my/products', () => {
      fetchMyData(baseUrl, page)
  );

  // button click callback
  const onBtnClick = ()=> {
     setPage(page+1)
  }
  return <div>
       ...
       <button onClick={() => onBtnClick()}>Next</button>
  </div>
}
```

As you can see, I have a `page` state, I wished that every time when the button is clicked, the `useSWR` wrapped function `fetchMyData(baseUrl, page)` will be triggered to fetch data again for the new page number.

However, the behaviour now is that the component does get re-rendered when button clicked, but the `fetchMyData(baseUrl, page)` is not triggered at all.

How to fix it to have the fetch data be triggered when `setPage(...)` is called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to do pagination. Here is SWR's page on pagination:
https://swr.vercel.app/docs/pagination

You need to include the `page` state variable in the string you pass as your `useSWR` hook's first argument. Then the hook should take care of the rest.

```js
const someFetcherFunction = (url) => {
  // fetch and return data from url
};

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [page, setPage] = useState(1);
  const { data, error } = useSWR('/my/products?page=${page}', someFetcherFunction);

  const onBtnClick = () => { setPage(prev => prev + 1); };

  return <button onClick={() => onBtnClick()}>Next</button>;
};
```